# Screen Readers and multiple "<footer>" elements

Tags: html, accessibility, footer

I have read that screen readers want to use only 1 time the "footer" element on the page
But I have also read that you can use the footer inside "section" element

What is the correct syntax?

Can we use the footer inside the section?
Can we use the footer multiple times on a page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer — `<footer>` *can* indeed appear multiple times a page. So it is correct syntax as used as such according the specification .. *permitted parents*: “Any element that accepts flow content. Note that a <footer> element must not be a descendant of an <address>, <header> or another <footer> element.”

Comment: ..as far as accessibility, my suggestion would be try out various readers and see if the page (and/or with the footers) is expressed well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we use the footer inside the section? Can we use the footer multiple times on a page?

Can you?  Yes, according to the [official html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-footer-element).

*Should you?*  I would try to avoid it.  You typically have one main footer and it's rare a page is organized to have multiple footers.  However, if you have section elements such as an `<article>` or `<aside>` there *might* be situations where those sections have their own footers.

```
<header></header>
...
<main>
  ...
  <article>
    <header></header>
    ...
    <footer></footer>
  </article>
  ...
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Same is true for `<header>`.

Comment: is a good practice to use multiple footers with aria-label? The the screen reader can separate them with the label. When the user opens the list with the landmarks, he could distinguish them from the title. The main issue will be the number of footers which can be bad... Try to find the "one" footer

Comment: Yes, if you must have multiple footers, it’s a good idea to distinguish them from each other via `aria-label`.